# MySQL unrepeatable rows search query

Tags: php, mysql

I save some images in my database. Each images have a "tags" property.
I'm gonna show "search by tags" result to users, but there is a problem.
For example, "**IMAGE1**" has "c#, programming, scripting" tags and I'm gonna show every images which have "programming" and "scripting" tags. So If I do that, "**IMAGE1**" will be duplicated.

So how can I prevent this duplicating ?!
Thanks !!

Comment: use `select distinct`? `group by`?

Comment: You'll have to show some code in order to get an answer. Without code I can only suggest add results to an array where duplicate entries would overwrite themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` operator of MySQL to retrieve non-duplicates

```
SELECT DISTINCT `imagename`
FROM `images`
WHERE (`tags` = 'programming') OR (`tags` = 'scripting')
```

The conditions for `WHERE` may be different depending on your PHP code.

Comment: Since you have `tags` in the `SELECT` clause, it will still show both rows.

Comment: @Barmar Correct, fixed and thanks